# Share single implementation of jest mocked module across multiple tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

### Context

I want to share a mocked module across multiple tests without having to copy and paste the custom implementation all the time.

We use the `next-i18next` library to handle our translations and with it comes a hook called `useTranslations()` which returns the `t` function. Generally it gets called as follows:

```
// SomeComponent.tsx
export const SomeComponent: FunctionComponent = () => {
...   
  const { t } = useTranslation('common')
...
}
```

When testing `SomeComponent.tsx` the setup generally looks as follows with the `useTranslations()` hook mocked out using `jest.mock(...)` at the top of the file below the imports.

```
// SomeComponent.test.tsx

// imports

jest.mock('next-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({
    t: (e) => e
  })
}))


describe('SomeComponent tests', () => {
  
  test('should do something', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

This works quite well with the exception that I have to copy and paste the `jest.mock(...)` section in every test where the `useTranslation()` hook is used. We have a lot of components and a lot of them use `useTranslation`

### Actual Issue

I've tried following the guide set out here by using the `__mocks__` folder approach: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

My directory structure has been setup to look something like this:

```
...
├── node_modules
├── __mocks__
│   └── next-i18next.ts
├── src
    └──SomeComponent
       ├── SomeComponent.test.tsx
       └── SomeComponent.tsx
├── other.ts
...
```

and I've then added a simple `jest.mock` at the top of the `SomeComponent.test.tsx` file so that it looks like this

```
// SomeComponent.test.tsx

// imports

jest.mock('next-i18next')

describe('SomeComponent tests', () => {
  
  test('should do something', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

But it doesn't really work and I always seem to run into the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _nextI18next.useTranslation) is not a function
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

#### Edit

For the mock I essentially tried doing what they demonstrated in the docs with `fs`

```
// __mocks__/next-i18next.ts

const nexti18next = jest.createMockFromModule('next-i18next')

nexti18next.useTranslation = () => ({
   t: (e) => e
})

module.exports = nexti18next
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example? And also [here in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) you can see that "*There's no need to explicitly call jest.mock('module_name').*"

Comment: Yeah I've tried without the explicit `jest.mock(...)` too. I will get you an example soon.

Comment: Have you tried this approach? https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestcreatemockfrommodulemodulename

Comment: Can you share how you implemented the file under __mocks__ folder? Probably some issue on how you exported the function.

Comment: Could you let us know if/how you solved this problem? I'm looking to do the exact same thing and having a hard time figuring it out. If someone out there would be willing to create a codesandbox or the like of how to set this up (using a file in the __mocks__ folder to generate mocks for libraries in the node_modules folder and using it in tests throughout the app), I would really appreciate it.